# Making FLANN matcher editable and savable to disk?

Tags: python, opencv, flann, flannbasedmatcher

I have my FLANN matcher here:

```
flann_params = dict(algorithm = 1, trees = 4)   
matcher = cv2.FlannBasedMatcher(flann_params, {})
```

I add descriptors of training images to it in a loop and then I train it:

```
matcher.add([descriptors])
matcher.train()
```

Few more related methods:

```
matcher.clear()
matcher.empty()
```

Both clear the train descriptor collection (right?)

But what I really want is:

1. Store the descriptors to disk and simply load them into the matcher and then train it
   OR
   Save the matcher data to disk so that I don't have to train images everytime I run the program.
2. Make the matcher editable: if I delete an image off the disk, it shouldn't be found by the matcher. Maybe something like `matcher.clear(index_of_image_deleted)`